# Bootstrap Modal is not scrolling in iPhone browsers after dismissing the Keyboard

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap modals. After presenting the modal in iPhone safari browser, modal is scrolling fine. But when I present the keyboard and dismiss it then the modal is getting freeze and the background is scrolling.

When I change the orientation (portrait to landscape and again landscape to portrait) of the device, again its working fine and the modal is scrolling.